# Display of product attributes the same attributes group into two sections

Tags: php, attributes, prestashop, smarty

I would like to divide the display of product attributes into two sections (front). Create two arrays, one with attributes with "premium" in the name and the other with the rest. Or sort them by ID.

I would ask for help in guiding how to do this.
I am not asking for a complete solution, tips are enough.

This is how it is now:
[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCYKZ.png)
This is the effect I want:
[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K9OE.png)

Answer (score 1):

to achieve that you need to modify the tpl in your theme folder.
To be more specific the file you want to change is in `/themes/{yourThemeName}/templates/catalog/_partials/product_variants.tpl`
Using a simple `If` that checks for the attribute name (or the presence of "premium" in that name) you can then group the obtained data in an array and print in a separate html portion.
I hope you know something about Smarty templating engine, it is not difficult at all.

Let me know if it helps.

Thanks,

Simone